# PageSpeed Insights: Minimize main-thread work - Debugging this with Chrome DevTools?

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools, pagespeed-insights

In attempting to profile the performance of a site with PageSpeed tools i get a vague minimize main thread work suggestion as shown below:

[image: page speed report]

The Learn More link is not exactly helpful here. I can see that style & layout is a large portion, so i'm trying to profile the site using Chrome Dev Tools. After i run the performance trace, i can see all the style, layout, and repaint in the main thread.

Where i am stuck, and have not found a helpful guide is how to actually translate these events on the timeline into the actual DOM element, or styles that are causing the performance bottleneck or particular repaint. All of the examples i've been able to find show a very simple example with just a few elements on the page.

How do i trace down what is causing the largest style and layout bottlenecks in terms of actual code?

[image: Performance Profile]

Comment: Your second screenshot doesn't seem to contain a page load sequence. If you want to optimize page load then press the second button in profiler toolbar (also Ctrl-Shift-E hotkey). More info: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference

Comment: The URL in the above comment has changed, the new URL is https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/evaluate-performance/reference/